# Incrementing date which is stored in a variable using python

Tags: python, datetime, datepicker

I'm getting date from datepicker which is selected by the user and i'm storing it in a variable called 'pickup_date'. If today's time is greater than 2:00, the date should increment by one day. Following is the code which i tried, by this code m able to change today's date. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

or directly in if statement i can use the code means that ll be helpful for me.

```
pickup_date = request.params.get('schedule-pickup', datetime.datetime.now())
time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
print "customer entered date-->",pickup_date

if time > datetime.datetime.now().strftime('14:00'):
        next_day_pickup = request_params.get('schedule-pickup', datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
        print "incremented date-->",next_day_pickup
```

'schedule-pickup' is id of datepicker by which m getting the date, which is selected by user.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: i'm not able to increment the date which is stored in the variable 'pickup_date'...

Comment: I assume that `pickup_date` a string. What's the _exact_ format of the data in it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by what you're actually trying to do: do you want to run this "next day" logic only if the picked date is today?

It also seems that you're mixing up string and datetime instances. Stick to datetime.

In any case, here is how to move 1 day forward if the hour is after 14:00:

```
pickup_date = datetime.datetime.now()
if pickup_date.hour > 14:
    pickup_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: My _guess_ is that the OP wants to increment `pickup_date` if the current time is > 14:00.

Comment: Yes u r right... the date should increment only if current time is > 14:00